# Building a list of tuples from two lists

Tags: python, list, tuples, cartesian-product

I wrote this function:

```
def buildAllPairs(l1, l2):
      l=[]
      for s in l1:
          for p in l2:
               l.append((s, p))
      return l
```

but it works only when i use numbers in the lists, for the alphabet comes out NameError, could somebody tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Please add the code that gives you the error. Which arguments do you call the function with?

Comment: Seems fine to me, the error is probably in the code you didn't post

Comment: @silvado, zip has different semantics to what the OP is trying to accomplish

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([1, 'a'], [2, 'b']))
[(1, 2), (1, 'b'), ('a', 2), ('a', 'b')]
```

Note that `itertools.product()` itself returns an `itertools.product` object, essentially a generator, instead of a list.